# Android AVD is opening at top right of window

Tags: android

Please see this image.[image]

When I start AVD it opens the mobile window at the top right of my window screen and I can not drag it. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> while the window is focused. You'll get a small menu where you can select something like "move" using the arrows and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then you can move the window using the arrow buttons to the center of your screen.
I hope this works for your emulator window!

Answer (score 1):

Try press Shift + Right Click on the AVD icon on task bar and clic "Move". Now you can move the window anywhere